# Looking to dynamically assign columns to Api endpoint to pass to react app

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, azure

```
namespace EMD.Models.Dtos.AssetInfo
{
    using System.Data;

    using Integ.Base.Extensions;

    /// <summary>
    /// HandoverDto.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="EMD.Models.BaseDto" />
    public partial class HandoverDto : BaseDto
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the asset item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The asset item.
        /// </value>
        public string AssetItem { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the type of the sub.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The type of the sub.
        /// </value>
        public string SubType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The function.
        /// </value>
        public string Function { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The location.
        /// </value>
        public string Location { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the description.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The description.
        /// </value>
        public string Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the package.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The package.
        /// </value>
        public string Package { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the control line.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The control line.
        /// </value>
        public string ControlLine { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the chainage.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The chainage.
        /// </value>
        public decimal? Chainage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the serial no.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The serial no.
        /// </value>
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }

        public static HandoverDto ParseFromDataRow(DataRow row)
        {
            HandoverDto dto = new HandoverDto();
            dto.AssetItem = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(AssetItem), default(string));
            dto.SubType = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(SubType), default(string));
            dto.Function = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(Function), default(string));
            dto.Location = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(Location), default(string));
            dto.Description = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(Description), default(string));
            dto.Package = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(Package), default(string));
            dto.ControlLine = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(ControlLine), default(string));
            dto.Chainage = row.GetValue<decimal>(nameof(Chainage), default(decimal));
            dto.SerialNo = row.GetValue<string>(nameof(SerialNo), default(string));
            return dto;
        }
    }
}
```

```
import { api_urls } from "../../api/apiUrls";
import { GridOperations, IDefaultLayoutProps } from "../../interfaces/i_grid";
import GetColumn from "../DataUtils";
import { HandOverMenu } from "../Menu";
export const HandOverData: IDefaultLayoutProps = {
    MainSection: {
        AllowedOperations: [GridOperations.view, GridOperations.export],
        AuditTableKey: "",
        ExportModuleKey: "Handover",
        BaseAPI: api_urls.GetHandOver,
        GetAllEndpoint: () => {
            return api_urls.GetHandOver;
        },
        Columns: [
            GetColumn("Asset Item", "AssetItem", { pinned: "left", lockVisible: true }),
            GetColumn("Sub Type", "SubType"),
            GetColumn("Location", "Location"),
            GetColumn("SubType/Asset Description", "Description"),
            GetColumn("Package", "Package"),
            GetColumn("Tunnel Alignment", "ControlLine"),
            GetColumn("Chainage", "Chainage"),
            GetColumn("Serial No", "SerialNo"),
        ],
        DefaultSortColumn: "",
        SectionName: "HandOver",
        DefaultSortColumnOrder: null,
        Name: "Hand Over",
        PrimaryKey: "AssetItem",
    },
    PageName: "Hand Over",
    Menu: HandOverMenu,
};
```

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 
-- =============================================
                        -- Author:      <Author, , Name>
                        -- Create Date: <Create Date, , >
                        -- Description: <Description, , >
                        -- =============================================
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Handover_Export]    
                        (    
                            @ProjectId INT,
                            @package VARCHAR(200) =NUll,  
                         @PageIndex INT = 1,    
                         @PageSize INT = 10,    
                         @sortBy VARCHAR(250) = NULL,    
                         @sortDir VARCHAR(5) = 'ASC',    
                         @Filters VARCHAR(1000) = NULL,    
                         @UserId INT = NULL    
                        )    
                        AS    
                        BEGIN    
 
                     SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;    
                     SET NOCOUNT ON    
                     DECLARE @StrSql VARCHAR(MAX) = '',@HandoverSql VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @TotRows INT, @TempPagesQuery VARCHAR(MAX), @sqlfilters VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @Rows INT    
                     ,@WhereCondition VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @HandoverTableName VARCHAR(200) = '##TempHandover',@cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX),@createTableQuery NVARCHAR(MAX),
                     @selectColumns NVARCHAR(MAX),@CreateTableSql NVARCHAR(MAX),@delimiter CHAR(1) = ',',@packages VARCHAR(MAX),@colstr VARCHAR(MAX) = '',@columnDefinitions NVARCHAR(MAX);  
                    DECLARE @Values TABLE (Value VARCHAR(50));
   
                    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempPageNo') IS NOT NULL    
                     DROP TABLE #TempPageNo
 
                     IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#cols') IS NOT NULL    
                     DROP TABLE #cols      
   
                    CREATE TABLE #TempPageNo(TotRows INT)    
                    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##TempHandover') IS NOT NULL    
                      DROP TABLE ##TempHandover  
 
                    IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##Attributes') IS NOT NULL)
                    BEGIN
                        DROP Table ##Attributes
                    END
 
                    INSERT INTO @Values (Value)
                    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@package, @delimiter);
 
                    SELECT @packages = COALESCE(@packages + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Value, '''')
                    FROM @Values;
 
                    SET @packages = 'AND a.owner IN (' + @packages + ')';
 
 
                    SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(AttributeValue.Attribute)
                                        FROM AttributeValue where projectid=@ProjectId
                                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
 
                   
                    SET @columnDefinitions = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(AttributeValue.Attribute) + ' NVARCHAR(200)'
                                                    FROM AttributeValue where projectid=@ProjectId
                                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
 
                    SET @createTableQuery = 'CREATE TABLE ##Attributes (AssetItemID INT, ' + @columnDefinitions + ');';
                   
                    CREATE TABLE #cols (attribute VARCHAR(255));
                    INSERT INTO #cols (attribute)
                    SELECT AttributeValue.Attribute
                    FROM AttributeValue where projectid=@ProjectId
                   
                    SET @query =
                        'INSERT INTO ##Attributes
                        SELECT AssetItemID, ' + @cols + '
                        FROM (
                                SELECT i.AssetItemID, av.Attribute, CAST(i.Value AS NVARCHAR(200)) AS Value
                                FROM Item2Item i
                                INNER JOIN AttributeValue av ON av.AttributeValueID = i.SubTypeAttributeID
                                INNER JOIN AssetItem (NOLOCK) a ON a.AssetItemID = i.AssetItemID
                                WHERE a.ProjectID = ' +CAST(@ProjectId AS VARCHAR(10))+'
                                '+ ISNULL(@packages, '') +'
                        ) src
                        PIVOT (
                            MAX(Value) FOR [Attribute] IN (' + @cols + ')
                        ) AS piv;';
                   
                    SET @colstr = 'SELECT * FROM #cols ORDER BY Attribute ASC;';  
 
                    SET @selectColumns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'ISNULL(temp.' + QUOTENAME(AttributeValue.Attribute) + ', '''') ' +  QUOTENAME(AttributeValue.Attribute)
                    FROM AttributeValue where projectid=@ProjectId
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');
 
                    SET @CreateTableSql =
                        'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@HandoverTableName) + ' (
                            WBS NVARCHAR(100),
                            WBSDescription NVARCHAR(250),
                            prefix nvarchar(10),
                            AssetItem NVARCHAR(50),
                            SubType NVARCHAR(50),
                            [Location] NVARCHAR(50),
                            Description NVARCHAR(250),
                            Owner NVARCHAR(30),
                            ControlLine NVARCHAR(10),
                            Chainage DECIMAL,
                            ' + @columnDefinitions + '
                        );';
 
                    SET @HandoverSql =
                        'INSERT INTO ' + @HandoverTableName + '
                        SELECT
                            ISNULL(wbs.WBS, ''''),
                            ISNULL(wbs.description, '''')  AS WBSDescription,
                            ISNULL(a.prefix, ''''),
                            ISNULL(a.Asset, '''') AS AssetItem,
                            ISNULL(ast.SubType, ''''),
                            ISNULL(loc.Asset, '''') AS [Location],
                            ISNULL(a.Description, ''''),
                            ISNULL(a.Owner, ''''),
                            ISNULL(pcl.ControlLine, ''''),
                            ISNULL(aic.Chainage, 0) AS Chainage,
                            ' + @selectColumns + '
                        FROM AssetItem (NOLOCK) a
                        INNER JOIN AssetItem (NOLOCK) loc ON loc.AssetItemID = a.LocationId
                        LEFT JOIN AssetSubType (NOLOCK) ast ON ast.AssetSubTypeID = a.AssetSubTypeID
                        LEFT JOIN ##Attributes temp ON a.AssetItemID = temp.AssetItemID
                        LEFT JOIN AssetItemChainage (NOLOCK) aic ON aic.AssetItemID = a.AssetItemID
                        LEFT JOIN WBSCODE (NOLOCK) wbs ON wbs.wbscodeid = a.wbscodeid
                        LEFT JOIN ProjectControlLine (NOLOCK) pcl ON pcl.ProjectControlLineID = aic.ProjectControlLineID AND pcl.ProjectID = '+CAST(@ProjectId AS VARCHAR(10))+'  
                        WHERE a.ProjectID = '+CAST(@ProjectId AS VARCHAR(10))+'
                        AND loc.ProjectID = '+CAST(@ProjectId AS VARCHAR(10))+'
                        '+ ISNULL(@packages, '') +';';
                   
                    PRINT(@selectColumns);
                    EXEC(@createTableQuery);
                    EXEC(@query);
                    EXEC (@CreateTableSql);
                    EXEC (@HandoverSql);
                    EXEC(@colstr);
 
                     /*Filters*/    
                     IF(ISNULL(@Filters,'') <> '' AND @Filters <> 'null' AND ISNULL(@Filters,'') <> '[]')    
                     BEGIN    
                      IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempFilterString') IS NOT NULL    
                      DROP TABLE #TempFilterString    
   
                      CREATE TABLE #TempFilterString(FilterString VARCHAR(MAX))    
                     INSERT INTO #TempFilterString    
                      EXEC [dbo].[usp_RetrunFilterString] @Filters = @Filters    
   
                      SELECT TOP 1 @sqlfilters = FilterString FROM #TempFilterString    
                     END
 
                     SELECT @StrSql = 'SELECT * FROM '+@HandoverTableName +' WHERE 1=1 '    
     
                    IF(ISNULL(@sqlfilters,'') != '')    
                     BEGIN    
                            SET @WhereCondition =  @sqlfilters    
                        END    
   
                     IF(ISNULL(@sortBy,'') != '')    
                     BEGIN    
                      SET @StrSql = @StrSql +ISNULL(@WhereCondition ,'')+ ' ORDER BY ' + @sortBy + ' ' + @sortDir    
                     END    
                     ELSE    
                     BEGIN    
                      SET @StrSql = @StrSql+ISNULL(@WhereCondition ,'') + ' ORDER BY 1 ASC'      
                     END    
 
                       IF(@PageIndex <> -1)    
                     BEGIN    
                      SET @TempPagesQuery = 'INSERT INTO #TempPageNo  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM '+@HandoverTableName +'  WHERE 1=1 '    
                      IF(ISNULL(@PageIndex,0) = 0)    
                       SELECT @PageIndex = 1, @pageSize = 50    
                      SET @rows = (@PageIndex - 1) * @pageSize;    
   
                      SET @TempPagesQuery = @TempPagesQuery+' '+ISNULL(@WhereCondition ,'')    
                     --PRINT @TempPagesQuery    
                      EXEC(@TempPagesQuery)    
 
                      SELECT @TotRows = TotRows FROM #TempPageNo    
                      SET @StrSql = @StrSql +    
                     ' OFFSET ' + CAST(@rows AS VARCHAR(32)) + ' rows ' +    
                       ' fetch next ' + CAST(@PageSize AS VARCHAR(32)) + ' rows only;'    
   
                      SET @StrSql = @StrSql + ' SELECT '+CAST(@TotRows AS VARCHAR(32))+' TotalCount ,CASE WHEN '+CAST(@TotRows AS VARCHAR(32))+'%'+CAST(@PageSize AS VARCHAR(32))+' > 0 THEN '+CAST(@TotRows AS VARCHAR(32))+'/'+CAST(@PageSize AS VARCHAR(32))+'+1 ELSE '+CAST(@TotRows AS VARCHAR(32))+'/'+CAST(@PageSize AS VARCHAR(32))+' END TotalPages'    
     
                     --Print @StrSql
 
                     EXEC(@StrSql)    
                    END
                    END
GO
```

Currently I have assigned preset column names in the react and .NET application. Need to dynamically assign column names for different projects, stored procedure returns a table called #cols with column names for the api. if i could have some assistance in a way to dynamically assign column or a way to select all columns from table instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Need to dynamically assign column names for different projects, stored procedure returns a table called #cols with column names for the api.

***Firstly, Retrieve Column Names from the Stored Procedure Result.***

- Create a .NET controller to handle API requests. By that we can Implement an action method that executes the stored procedure to retrieve the column names dynamically.
- Fetch the column names from the temporary table `#cols` and Serialize the column names into JSON format and return them as the response.

**Controller.cs :**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespace.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ColumnsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly string connectionString = "your_connection_string_here";

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetColumns()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Your_Stored_Procedure_Name", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        dt.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Extract column names from DataTable
            var columnNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
            }

            return Ok(columnNames);
        }
    }
}
```

#### API Endpoint in React

- In React application, make an HTTP request to the API endpoint exposed by the .NET backend. Receive the column names in the React component and use the received column names to dynamically generate columns for the table or any other UI components.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function ColumnNamesComponent() {
    const [columnNames, setColumnNames] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://your-api-base-url/api/columns')
            .then(response => {
                setColumnNames(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching column names:', error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Column Names</h2>
            <ul>
                {columnNames.map((columnName, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{columnName}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ColumnNamesComponent;
```

Here in my case I have Converted DataTable to JSON.

```cs
// Convert DataTable to JSON or dynamic object 
     var data = ConvertDataTableToJson(dt);
     return Ok(data); 
}
```

The GET request triggers the `GetData` method in the `DataController`.

[image]